# Регулярное выражение: поиск подстроки содержащее заданное слово с исключением при другом слове

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Нужно распарсить html-документ и найти все начальные теги <div>, которые содержат определенное слово, но при этом исключить строки содержащие слово исключения.
Проблема в том, что слово исключения может находится как слева, так и справа от слова поиска. А кроме этого нужно выделить подстроку из всего текста.
Я просмотрел много различных решений, но все они имеют более легкую задачу - без выделения подстрок из многострочного текста.

Как пример:

```
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство2="значение2" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство2="значение2" свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство3="значение3" свойство1="значение1">
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">что-то еще</div></div></div>/div>
```

Нужно выбрать все  содержащие слово "свойство1" и не содержащие "свойство2".
Результат должен быть таким:

```
<div свойство3="значение3" свойство1="значение1">
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">
```

Возможно ли это сделать одним регулярным выражением или только двумя?
Т.е. за два шага, сначала выбрать все строки с входящим словом, а потом исключить с исключающим словом.

Comment: [Обязательное чтение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1892060).

Comment: Там совершенно другая задача. Мне не нужно распарсить документ с учетом всего многообразия тегов. Меня интересует конкретный тег с конкретными свойствами. И мне не нужен закрывающий тег вообще. Под мои условия может подойти любой текст, в котором нужно выделить подстроки (предложения, абзацы и т.п.) с определенным словом поиска, но не содержащие слово-исключение. Например, блокировщики рекламы позволяют использовать "регулярки" на html-страницах, хотя это не моя задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = `<div свойство1="значение1" свойство2="значение2" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство2="значение2" свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство3="значение3" свойство1="значение1">
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">что-то еще</div></div></div>/div>`;

const match = text.match(/<((?!свойство2).)*?(свойство1)((?!свойство2).)*?>/g);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, отлично работает. Хотя я вроде бы пытался подобным образом составить на основании более простых примеров исключения, но почему-то не удалось. Видимо, все же не хватает понимания и опыта в данной теме.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const htmlStr = `
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство2="значение2" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство2="значение2" свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">
<div свойство3="значение3" свойство1="значение1">
<div свойство1="значение1" свойство3="значение3">что-то еще</div></div></div>/div>
`;

const dom = document.createElement('html');
dom.innerHTML = htmlStr;

const res = dom.querySelectorAll('[свойство1]:not([свойство2])')
console.log([...res]);

const openTags = [...res].map(el => el.outerHTML.split('>')[0]+'>');
console.log(openTags);
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я просил с использованием RegEx, а не с использованием веб API.

Comment: Вы не единственный читатель вашего вопроса и ответов к нему. Корректная альтернатива не помешает.

Comment: Но в заголовке и в тегах другая постановка задачи. Вряд ли кто-то будет искать решение задачи парсинга через DOM в вопросах по RegEx.

Comment: Тому, кто будет искать решение задачи парсинга с помощью регулярных выражений будет полезным увидеть решение через dom. Вы хотите, чтобы я удалил этот ответ? Не удалю. =)

Comment: Нет, не хочу. Просто я считал данный ответ не соответствующим теме вопроса. Возможно я просто плохо знаю нюансы по данному вопросу. А удалять или нет пусть решают модераторы. Если не удалят значит соответствует нормам.

Comment: @Corhal, когда сразу несколько опытных людей говорят вам, что лучше гвозди все-таки забивать молотком, а не микроскопом, то, возможно, стоит отложить микроскоп в сторону и прислушаться к советам. Надеюсь моя аллегория понятна... :)

Comment: @MaxU аллегория понятна, но в контексте моей задачи неуместна. Как я написал выше в комментарии под вопросом, в моем случае код html может присутствовать не как самостоятельный документ, а как часть другого. И сам html может быть не полным, а всего лишь какой-то частью. И поэтому нормализовать такое в DOM не получиться. Т.е. когда у тебя шурупы, то тебе нужна отвертка и даже шуруповёрт без соответствующей насадки может не подойти. А тебе на просьбу помочь с отверткой, считая себя умнее, предлагают молоток. Надеюсь моя аллегория понятна. >/ Вот Евгений Платов помог не давая ненужных советов.

Comment: @MaxU в моем случае правда наоборот: у меня есть только один инструмент (RegEx), пусть будет та же отвёртка, но особая, например шестигранная. Соответственно,  мне нужны под нее соответствующие шурупы. Но мне предлагаю как раз молоток (JS), по каким-то своим причинам полагая, что у меня есть для него гвозди (DOM-документ). Надеюсь эта аллегория тоже будет понятна. Я ведь не просил додумывать за меня, что лучше использовать. Я просил конкретное решение под конкретные указанные мной условия.
Спасибо еще раз Евгению за помощь.